# How to simply change marker icon on click and then back to original state when click elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, icons, marker

I'm trying to get this function on my custom map https://rodadagua.netlify.app/

I've found some very close examples and questions on here but being a complete novice unfortunately I have no idea what I´m doing.

This is essentially the same question [Change (and change back) leaflet icon on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997247/change-and-change-back-leaflet-icon-on-click) but with such basic knowledge I can't work it out. Also I found this question [Leaflet map: on click changing color of all markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890461/leaflet-map-on-click-changing-color-of-all-markers) and example https://jsfiddle.net/vz7jmnqs/2/ is essentially what I'm after but again I can't work out how to include it in my code and make it work.

I want to change marker icon when clicked (so that it shows a different coloured version) and then return back to original state (original icon/colour) when click elsewhere, anywhere, eg. close the associated popup or click on the map or click on another marker.

The closet I've got to is I can change the icon on a click, but I want to change it back.

```
var defaultIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon.png',
    shadowUrl: 'scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
});

var brownIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-brown.png',
    shadowUrl: 'scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
});

var testmarker = L.marker([0.0, 0.0], {icon: defaultIcon}).addTo(map);

testmarker.on('click', function(e) {
  testmarker.setIcon(brownIcon);
});
```

I'm using the basic Leaflet script to define the map etc. then all of my markers and popups are set up like this example:

```
var marker_Waldemar = L.marker([15.0, -40.0]).addTo(map);
marker_Waldemar.bindPopup('<h3>EMEF Prof. Waldemar Rodrigues</h3><p><iframe src="https://galeriafeira.netlify.app/" width="500" height="354" style="border:none;"></iframe></p><p><b>Feira de Ci&ecirc;ncias</b></p>', {
    maxWidth : 520,
    maxHeight : 450,
});
```

I would like to know exactly what code I need to put in and where.

Comment: Hello. Your handcrafted map is very beautiful. By the way, how did you published a XYZ layer ?

Comment: @halfer thank you. Hopefully I'll find a way ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").click(function(){
  testmarker.setIcon(defaultIcon);
});
```

It will do the job!

Comment: thank you very much! @ronangr1 where do I put this ? after testmarker2.on('click', function(e) {
  testmarker2.setIcon(myIcon2);
});

Comment: is "body" something I need to have already defined earlier in the code ? I´ve tried put it in after the click on function and it doesn´t seem to have an effect and also clears all subsequent listed makers from the map

Comment: @andycb put it after your variables declaration

Comment: thank you @ronangr1 that solves the problem of clearing any subsequent markers (putting it after them) but it is still not having the desired affect, the marker stays in its clicked state and doesn´t change back, it doesn´t seem to make any difference. any ideas? i really wish it was that simple !